# Angular 2: how to redirect user to previous URL after login

Tags: angular, redirect, aspnetboilerplate

I am using ABP Angular template. I am looking for a way to redirect user to the URL that he has requested initially after authentication happens. For example if user put localhost:4200/app/plan/1 which only allow authenticated users, then framework redirects the user to the login page and when the user gets authenticated automatically gets redirected to the address requested earlier. At the moment user gets redirected to home component

Why the `initialUrl` in the `login.service.ts` is always 'localhost:4200'?

```
var initialUrl = UrlHelper.initialUrl;
    if (initialUrl.indexOf('/login') > 0) {
        initialUrl = AppConsts.appBaseUrl;
    }
    location.href = initialUrl;
```

Comment: Triggering back button via code is enough for you right?

Comment: @aaron, any idea on why for authentication user first gets redirected to localhost:4200 then to login page? That is why the intitialUrl is always localhost:4200 and lost the actual requested URL

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location :Location){}

loginAction(){
     //Do login request 

     //Login Success callback
     this.location.back();
     //Login Failed callback
     Do nothing
}
```

Comment: that still redirects me to localhost:4200!